# iOS architecture and components

Tags: objective-c, ios, architecture, structure, reusability

For quite a while I've been looking at objective c examples, watching the Stanford lectures, and playing around with some code to get a hang of creating an iOS app.

However there are a few things that I can't find a good answer on:

1. How do I properly separate my layers? I understand the MVC structure, and I saw some examples of creating Categories for models to implement business logic. Is that the proper way, by enriching models or should I create dedicated classes (e.g. to authenticate users, extract models from json, group orders)?
2. How smart should views be? Can I make a view that displays a Contact (by assigning the contact property) or should I create separate properties for all of the Contact fields or should the view request it's information via a delegate call?
3. I'm using a Storyboard in my application. On my screen I want to
   have a navigation bar, and let's say a view that displays orders. On
   other screens I want to reuse the order-view.

   - How can I re-use the order-view's ViewController and View in other ViewControllers?
   - If I have 4 screens with the same look-and-feel, do I have to simply copy them in the Storyboard? This seems like a pain to main, what if I want to change my background? Or add a button to all of the views? When I create a setup-wizard I don't want to define the look-and-feel for every screen separately.

Coming from a C# background I probably have to get into the objective-c mindset :)
Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) ObjC-Categories will easily distort your understanding of the main problem you're facing. **ObjC-Categories are completely unnecessary**. You could always approach these extensions by subclassing, object composition, additional methods in the actual model, or some customization in the controller or view. So if you need to format data (e.g. which is present in the model) for display in a view -- that task would often land in the controller. As far as the examples you provide: You may opt for models in simple cases -- as well, any of the examples could merit dedicated class, if complex enough or if it would keep you from redundant implementation. Note that these may be accessory classes, which simply produce a model, or they may be composites of multiple concrete of abstract classes. Not everything needs to land squarely in the definition of **M-or-V-or-C**. You're free to use many design patterns with ObjC. Think of MVC as the patterns Cocoa typically uses -- you will need to know them, and you will need to know how to subclass and extend these types, but these patterns lose dominance as implementations move away from Cocoa's libraries (e.g. as complexity increases).

2) They can be smart. However, under MVC, you want to focus its implementation on the view/presentation aspect. A view which represents a collection of information could in fact perform some tasks which are typically reserved for the controller -- however, you would generally cede that the implementation were a dedicated `MONContactView` in doing so. If you go that route, you would generally do so for easy reusability or to achieve a simple interface. Displaying information about a `Contact` could be very complex - In simple scenarios, these tasks are often handled by the controller. Specifically, a `MONAwesomeContactView` is likely less complex (e.g. in SLOC) than `MONAwesomeContactViewController` (unless  you have some very special drawing or layout to perform). It would be more common to set the controller's contact, and let the controller push the contact data to the views' fields. Again, in the case of a very specialized subclass -- a view could very well hold its own controllers in some cases.

3a) There's nothing wrong with creating multiple instances of a class.

3b) No need to copy. When duplication is smelled, I push the implementation to actual code -- the programs can apply the look and feel you desire, or add or manipulate the subviews as you desire. Of course, they will not be present in Xcode's NIB editor. There are of course alternate approaches, but this replication often makes me move the implementation to compiled code. Achieving a good balance of both is not so difficult (personally, I do most of my views programmatically, rather than using NIBs).

Comment: Nice to see that there are other folks here who aren't fooled by IB. Me too, I'm creating views programmatically - those XIB/NIB/WTF files really suck. They add unnecessary complexity and reduce flexibility (especially if I want to add some dynamism).

Comment: @H2CO3 up top! :) i sometimes find XIBs useful for prototypes and that occasional view that requires no real specialization… but a hassle when the time comes to write/maintain actual programs. more on my op/ex here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816964/designing-the-iphone-interface-in-a-nib-or-in-code/1817964#1817964 coincidentally(?), i've spent a good chunk of time today cleaning up XIBs created by another engineer -- and there's a sizable hill of both problems and redundancy within them = = …but what do i know? i'm primarily a low-level guy - haha.

Comment: don't say anything! :D I'm freaked out by people who stick to their idea about C being 'an ugly very low-level language...'

Comment: @H2CO3 hahaha - well, i've seen (and even written!) ugly C programs… are you insinuating that was not caused by some fault in the language?!?!?!?!??!?! =)

Comment: @Justing don't take me wrong, me too! :P but I still feel C is the best programming language I know about. As Mr Torvalds writes in his Kernel coding style guide: any sane person knows that K&R are right. :)

Comment: @H2CO3 well, you may not like to hear this; i wind up using a "lean n' mean subset of C++" for low level stuff most of the time. C++ has so many features - i avoid using a good chunk of them (exceptions being the most controversial), but there are also a lot of first class language features i've really grown attached to (real time applications are common here) -- so i use a lot of C++. most importantly, LINUS IS HILARIOUS!!

Comment: I didn't say C++ is bad. I said I aggree with Linus of not liking C++. (I think I'll eventually need to dig deeper into it.)

Comment: @H2CO3 i know you didn't say C++ is bad :) i only said you may not like to hear i write a lot of C++, after your comment about C.

Comment: Practically, I don't care how many code and in which language others write :D as long as 1. I don't have to maintain their code 2. their write good quality code which runs fast and doesn't leak memory etc. Provided that you claim yourself being a low-level developer, I trust you writing good code :)

Comment: exactly - for example: i don't mind using a java app on OS X, if it's the tool which enables me to do what i need to do in a fraction of the time. also, correctness, performance, scalability and leaks are common subjects of bug reports i submit - i rarely suggest new features.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have a few good websites with XCode design patterns? (recent ones based on iOS 5)

Comment: @Zyphrax nothing's really coming to mind - i don't read nearly as much as i write, and much of that read time is here at SO. I think SO's got great contributors - but a bit of searching to do. try just browsing the top answerers' best answers -- http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cocoa/topusers. i've also linked a book - if i wanted to read about design patterns in objc, that is what i would choose. however, there are a few areas you may need to fill in. http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Developers-Library-ebook/dp/B002RAPB46/ref=sr_1_46?ie=UTF8&qid=1345014688&sr=8-46&keywords=cocoa+development

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a pretty abstract question and it's not clear what oh mean by 'layers'. Yes, you should create your own classes where appropriate, but categories also give you the option of adding functionality to existing classes. If you can be more specific with the question it'll be easier to provide a better answer.
2. It's a judgement call. If you want to create a view class that knows how to display an instance of your Contact type, that's fine in my book. If that view knows where Contacts are stored in the app, though, that's not so good.
3. Remember that the things in a storyboard are objects, not classes. You don't want to try to re-use a view from one scene in another scene -- that'd mean sharing a view between scenes, which really won't work. If you want to use the same order-view in several places, that'd be a good candidate for creating a class. On the other hand, you *can* set up your storyboard so that several different scenes all transition to the same scene. If you want different parts of your app to modally display a scene that displays an order, for example, you can do that.

Comment: With layers I mean: application layers (e.g. classic UI / Business / Data). The Categories seem like a good way to extend Core Data entities.